# GetPixel always returns CLR_INVALID

Tags: winapi, gdi

I'm trying to read the pixel color of a given window. The window is not mine. The window may not have focus or be at foreground. I don't know if it matters, does it? I have the window handle, so I do:

```
  HDC hdc = GetDC(m_window);
  if (hdc) 
  {
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(hdc,x,y);

    if(color == CLR_INVALID)
    {
      wxLogDebug("COLOR DATA INVALID");        
    }
    else
    {
      wxLogDebug("COLOR DATA 0x%x", color);
    }
```

x and y are screen coordinates that lie inside the window. Don't know why this is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should convert x, y into client coordinates with [ScreenToClient Function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This sounds right.  I know GetPixel returns `CLR_INVALID` if the pixel is clipped.  If you've got the wrong coordinates, you're likely outside the clipping region for the window's client area.

Comment: That isn't the problem, I `SetPixel()` and get the right result. I also confirm lots [conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129421/windows-api-getpixel-always-return-clr-invalid-but-setpixel-is-worked).