# Windows API `GetPixel()' always return `CLR_INVALID`, but `SetPixel()` is worked well?

Tags: winapi

My OS is windows 7 64-bits with 2 monitors display.

I use `GetPixel()`, but it always return `CLR_INVALID` as result like that:

```
COLORREF result = GetPixel(dc,x,y);
```

My `GetDeviceCaps(RASTERCAPS)` returns result that `RC_BITBLT` is enabled.
`GetDeviceCaps(COLORMGMTCAPS)` returns result is `CM_GAMMA_RAMP`.

Most importantly, if I `SetPixel(dc,x,y,RGB(250,250,250))` in advance, and `GetPixel(dc,x,y)` later, I can **ALWAYS** retreive correct result like that:

```
COLORREF result = SetPixel(dc,x,y,RGB(250,250,250));
COLORREF cr = GetPixel(dc,x,y);
```

So I think my coordination should be alright. I have no idea about why `GetPixel()` always return `CLR_INVALID`, but `SetPixel()` is always worked well? Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetPixel always returns CLR\_INVALID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496120/getpixel-always-returns-clr-invalid)

Comment: I don't think so. I `SetPixel()` and get the right result, and `GetPixel()` after it get right result,too. Coordination isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation

> A bitmap must be selected within the device context, otherwise,
>   CLR_INVALID is returned on all pixels.

Try the below code and see if it works for your device context.

```
HDC dc = ... // <-- your device context
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
HBITMAP memBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, 1, 1);
SelectObject(memDC, memBM);

int x = ... // point's coordinates
int y = ...
BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, dc, x, y, SRCCOPY);

COLORREF cr = GetPixel(memDC, 0, 0);
std::cout << cr << std::endl;

DeleteDC(memDC);
DeleteObject(memBM);
```

Comment: I know your point and I think this may work. Because I can `GetPixel()` correctly after I `SetPixel()` at the same point. I'll try your code later times.

Comment: *"the selected object is a brush"* - That doesn't make sense. A device context always has one of each object selected into it. It's not like the last call to `SelectObject` somehow activates that object type. It merely replaces that object type slot with a new object. Please see [Device Contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx) for an introduction.

Comment: For more context, the reason this needs to be done is because CreateCompatibleDC returns a HDC with a 1x1 monochrome bitmap and GetPixel won't work on that.  
Thus you need to select a color bitmap into the HDC.  
Also of note is the example code here is missing a matching SelectObject before DeleteDC, the first SelectObject should be `HGDIOBJ restoreBM = SelectObject(memDC, memBM);` and before DeleteDC you want a `SelectObject(memDC, restoreBM);` otherwise you will leak a bitmap.