# GetPixel() not working correctly Windows API C++

Tags: c++, winapi, getpixel, gdi

I'm writing a program that reads each pixel of a window and store it in an array of bytes as black and white, each bit of the bytes is a black/white value.

But `GetPixel()` doesn't seem to work the way I expected. Here's the part of the code for reading pixels and storing them:

```
byte *colors = new byte[250000 / 8 + 1];
ZeroMemory(colors, 250000 / 8 + 1);
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP memBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 500, 500);
SelectObject(memDC, memBitmap);
BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, 500, 500, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

for (int y = 0; y < 500; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
        COLORREF pxcolor = GetPixel(memDC, x, y);
        if (pxcolor == CLR_INVALID) {
            MessageBox(hwnd, _T("Oops..."), NULL, NULL);
        }
        int r = GetRValue(pxcolor);
        int g = GetGValue(pxcolor);
        int b = GetBValue(pxcolor);
        int average = (r + g + b) / 3;
        bool colorBW = average >= 128;

        int currentIndex = y * 500 + x;
        if (colorBW) {
            SetBit(colors, currentIndex);
        }
    }
}
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
DeleteDC(memDC);
DeleteObject(memBitmap);
delete[] colors;
```

`SetBit()`:

```
inline VOID SetBit(byte *bytes, int index, bool state = true) {
    byte byteToSet = bytes[index / 8];
    int bitNumber = index % 8;
    bytes[index / 8] = state ? (byteToSet | (0b1000'0000 >> bitNumber)) : (byteToSet & ((0b1111'1111 >> (bitNumber + 1)) | (0b1111'1111 << (8 - bitNumber - 1))));
}
```

Every pixel read in by `GetPixel()` seems to give me 0x000000, or pure black.

My code *used to* call `GetPixel()` with the first parameter being `hdc`, without all the bitmap and memory DC stuff, but that way every pixel returns `CLR_INVALID`. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129421/windows-api-getpixel-always-return-clr-invalid-but-setpixel-is-worked) question, and the above code is after I have changed it into using memory DCs and bitmaps. But it just went from returning `CLR_INVALID` to `0x000000` for each pixel.

If I add this line before I use `GetPixel()`:

```
SetPixel(memDC, x, y, RGB(255, 255, 255));
```

`GetPixel()` returns the correct result. Why is it functioning this way?

Comment: Make sure hwnd is valid. For example use `hwnd = GetDesktopWindow()` --- This size calculation is wrong `= 250000 / 8 + 1`

Comment: Why are you even calling `GetPixel`? You already copied the screen contents into memory, accessible through the bitmap you created. All that's left is a call to [GetDIBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879.aspx). See [Capturing an Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402.aspx) for sample code.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the advice, but it did not work... Here's the code I've changed:
 Before the for loops:
`COLORREF *pixels = new COLORREF[250000];
BITMAPINFO bInfo;
bInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = 500;
bInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = 500;
bInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
bInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
GetDIBits(memDC, memBitmap, 0, 500, pixels, &bInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);`

and in the for loops

`COLORREF pxcolor = pixels[currentIndex];`